# Cannot SSH into Elastic Beanstalk error(64, 'Host is down') given

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm unable to SSH to my Elastic Beanstalk environment. When I run

```
eb ssh my-envname --debug
```

I get the following

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-elasticbeanstalk/3.7.8/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/aws.py", line 283, in make_api_call
    raise ServiceError(error)
ebcli.objects.exceptions.ServiceError: ('Connection aborted.', error(64, 'Host is down'))
```

I'm not sure why this is, in security groups I have opened up the SSH port 22 for my IP Address.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the Little Snitch on my MacOS was blocking EB SSH connections (oops).

Answer (score 1):

Run the eb init command with the --interactive option which temporarily opens port 22 in your environment's security group for incoming traffic from 0.0.0.0/0.

If you have configured your environment's security group to open port 22 to a restricted CIDR range for increased security, the EB CLI will respect that setting and forgo any changes to the security group. To override this behavior and force the EB CLI to open port 22 to all incoming traffic, use the --force option.

You can refer below link for more details:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, this wasn't my actual issue, turned out my computers firewall (Little Snitch for Mac) was blocking EB SSH requests. However I think your answer would be the correct answer for many people with this issue.